# Matrix Interpolation Algorithm

Tags: interpolation, multidimensional-array, linear-interpolation

I'm working with a large set of coordinate points that I need to interpolate between.  Basically what it is, is the temperature at various latitudes and longitudes.  I'd like to interpolate to get the temperature at round latitudes and longitudes.

For example, I know that at

44.56N, 56.42W, Temp=50

47.82N, 57.845 W, Temp= 44.2 Degrees

45.74N, 59.216 W, Temp =60.1 Degrees

I'd like to take this data and interpolate the temperature at 46.0N 58.0 W.  Can some one point me in the right direction?  I'm not even sure where to start.  Even some pseudo code or a Wikipedia link would be helpful.  The interpolation doesn't have to be too precise, just has to get me in the ball park.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I suppose the easiest approach that would be just an approximation would be weighted distances (average temperatures at each point, weighting for distance from the target point). To determine distance look at: [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) or http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.

If you wanted a better interpolation approach, consider areal interpolation. I don't know how well that would apply to specific points rather than areas, but seems like the most applicable approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  My thought was to do a weighted distance approach and I went ahead and implemented that.  However, I have about 60,000 coordinates, so looking at all the coordinates for each interpolation I want to calculate is very slow.  I was thinking of creating some sort of data structure that would allow for quick access of nearby points, so I'm not having to look at all 60,000 each time.  Any ideas for how that could work? Or a different approach to trim down the data set?

Comment: Several options. If you're using a geo-spatial enabled database, use the geo query functions to select all points within some distance from your desired point, then just use those.

Comment: If it's a data structure, you could write your own quick test of points within a certain distance (box search would be quick, though 60k points is a lot). The other aspect of that is a good point... how to get a good selection of points around it... if you had only the 10 closest points, but all were in one direction from your target point, that's not a good answer. So you might pick closest four points based on +/- lat/lon or within certain angles (one or two closest points in each quadrant). All those take more computation, though.

Comment: That's a good thought, I like the closest 4 points in each quadrant idea.  I'm still a little unsure as to how to find those points however.  You mentioned box search, which I'm not familiar with.  I tried to google it, but couldn't find anything that looked right.  Can you point me in the right direction on that?  Thanks!

Comment: By box search I just meant compare X and Y, assuming a simple box of X+n units, X-n units, and check that the existing lat/lon point is between X-n and X+n (same with Y). That's a really quick way to filter down to a reasonable number of points (although 60k is still a lot to search through). You might consider keeping your 60k points broken down into a grid, know which are in each grid (and maybe overlap those grids a little); then you find the grid cell for your desired point and only compare against points in that same grid cell. Takes more memory, but would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this, I ended up storing my data points in a Quadtree and then using the query range method to find the two nearest coordinates in each quadrant.  Then I do an inverse distance average based on each points distance from the target coordinate.  This seems to be giving pretty good results, but the run time is a little slow.  Loading my 60,000 data points into a quadtree takes about 30 seconds. Then it takes about another minute to query that data to calculate 2500 points.  I'll update if I come up with anything faster.